# Bad Xcode iPhone simulator performance - Python Kivy app

Tags: python, iphone, xcode, kivy, ios-simulator

I'm running a application that I created using Python and KivyMD in the iPhone Simulator of Xcode. So far I do have a really bad performance. The animations, transistions, opening/ widgets just perform very bad and laggy. It results in a delay of mouse click and instruction performance of about 1s. The app I developed is yet pretty simple, does contain several basic widgets like a button, textinput, spinners and does have a connection to a postgreSQL database. Not the functions in the app (select data from the database etc) cause the lag, it's just the performance in total.

Is there anything that has to be set up in Xcode to make it run smooth? Already checked if I had accidentally enabled the **slow-animations** but didn't. Also curious if it is just the simulator or if it would also run as bad on my actual device.

Answer (score 1):

I've used Kivy to develop a number of iOS apps. The iPhone simulator from Xcode is just tremendously slow no matter what. Your program likely runs just fine on a physical device!

Comment: You‘re right - the application performs very well on my physical device. Transition are very smooth and do not show any of the simulator lags!

Answer (score 0):

The iPhone simulator is runs super heavy on a system. I've experienced something similar and was able to fix it by closing applications running in the background to free up some CPU and RAM. You could also try the obvious restarting xcode.

Comment: Even when I just have the simulator itself and the postgre server running it still has some performance issues. I‘m just wondering because the preview window using PyCharm runs a lot faster and displays the application smoother than the XCode simulator. Restarting and a new clean build of the application also did not show any significant improvements.